# Setting attr of dynamically created input box from same created select

Tags: jquery, dynamic, closest

I need to set the place holder of a dynamically created input box

http://jsfiddle.net/ec1zsmcz/

The 'problem' line is here:

```
 $('input[name="search[]"]').eq($(this).index()).attr('placeholder', 'YYYY-MM-DD');
```

I tried

```
$(this).closest('input[name="search[]"]').attr('placeholder', 'YYYY-MM-DD');
```

But that didn't work.

It's currently just populating the top input box... I want it to set the corresponding input box

Answer (score 1):

try this:-

```
$(this).parents('tr').find('input[name="search[]"]').attr('placeholder', 'YYYY-MM-DD');
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/lastuser/ec1zsmcz/6/)

Comment: Perfect!! It's nice to learn s'thing today!! Thanks so much. Fiddle updated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the closest ancestor that contains the group of controls (tr) and search down:

```
$(this).closest('tr').find('input[name="search[]"]').attr('placeholder', 'YYYY-MM-DD');
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/ec1zsmcz/3/

Comment: Down-voter care to comment? A *later* near-identical answer has been up-voted?

Answer (score 0):

Try to trigger the `.change()` initially for getting the expected result after the page loads,

```
$('.searchSelect').change(function(){
    var cache = $(this).closest('tr').find('input[name="search[]"]');
    cache.attr('placeholder', $(this).val().lastIndexOf('Dates|', 0) === 0 ? 'YYYY-MM-DD' : "");
}).change();
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ec1zsmcz/5/)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie I don't see any changes in terms of functionality while comparing mine with your fiddle except the elegance in mine.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Don't speculate. I didn't. :D

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie I didn't agree to join in your club. The foolish club.